# MovieClip is causing permanent memory leaks

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, memory-leaks, air, movieclip

I'm getting pretty stumped about why this movieclip function is causing a permanent memory leak.  The way it works is it loads a random movieclip based on a string, changes a textfield value inside of that movieclip, tweens it, then removes it.

I've reduced to this barebones example of adding and remove it, and if I run the function a few times it still causes permanent memory increases.

```
    public function randomRolls(e:MouseEvent):void {
            var tempClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("d3MC") as Class;
            var tempMC:MovieClip = new tempClass() as MovieClip;

            addChild(tempMC);
            removeChild(tempMC);
            tempClass = null;
            tempMC = null;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the code for your d3MC class?  Have you tried this measuring this function's memory use when a different class is used (like a regular MovieClip) for tempClass?

Comment: What do you mean by permanent memory leaks? You know that the GC is called over time and you have to wait a little before the your child gets collected, right? And I thing @Gigggas is right - there might be something within your `d3MC` that block it from being collected.

Comment: It's a bitmap image (a dice image) and a textfield about 100x100 in width.  I removed the textfield for the above sample to try to narrow it down, but whenever I press the button that runs the function the memory use just gets higher and higher without going back down with garbage collections.

Comment: Update:  I think I mostly got rid of it.  I did more testing it the memory seemed to reach a cap after I removed the textfield, so the issue lies with that most likely.  I think I'll see how converting the text to a bitmap at runtime works for me.

Comment: You may have known about this, but for reference, `System.gc` [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#gc%28%29] is useful for forcing garbage collection for debugging

Comment: @JKillian It is generally recommended that you not use `System.gc()` for a production application. It doesn't actually force GC to run, just tells the system it is ready. Additionally, GC is meant to be done automatically in Flash to avoid unnecessary CPU time. If you run it and then the app needs the CPU to do something (i.e. user interaction), you're going to drop frames. The built-in system largely avoids that.

Comment: @JoshJanusch, you are absolutely correct. That's what I had meant when I mentioned that it was good 'for debugging' but your clarification is good to note

Comment: @JKillian The 'for debugging' was pushed down to the next line. I completely missed it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ha ha no worries - while we're at it might as well mention `System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent()` [ http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent%28%29 ] which is useful for production